# Understanding Joint discrete R.V

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics

I'm working on this question but I don't know how to do it despite having the solutions.

If p X,Y(x, y) = cxy at the points (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2) and (3, 1), and equals 0 elsewhere, ﬁnd c.

I can understand that all pdf (including joints) add up to 1, but I don't know the process of doing it.

The working out was $c*\sum_{all X,Y} P(x,y) = 1$, but how do you find $\sum_{all X,Y}P(x,y)$ since discrete R.V. can't be solved with the marginal PDF. Looking at the answer, it seems you multiply each (x,y) coordinate together but is there any explanation why? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $P(x,y)= cxy$. That means that the point $(1, 1)$ has a probability of $c\cdot 1\cdot 1=c$. So your sum is

$$P(1,1)+P(2,1)+P(2,2)+P(3,1)=c\cdot 1\cdot 1+ c\cdot 2\cdot 1+ c\cdot 2\cdot 2+ c\cdot 3\cdot 1=1$$

Is it comprehensible?

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes sense!

Comment: I pleases me, that all is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Just... add them up.

$$\sum_{x,y}\mathsf P(x,y)= \mathsf P(1, 1)+\mathsf P(2, 1)+\mathsf P(2, 2)+\mathsf P(3, 1)$$